# Given slope of incline is 1 in 20, how to interpret this mathematically?

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

So what I have is an pretty dumb level question of work power energy which goes as follows:

A man cycles up a hill whose slope is $1$ in $20$ with a velocity of $6.4$ km/hr along the hill. The weight of the man and the cycle is $98$ kg. What work per minute is the man doing? What is his horse power.

So my first thoughts go towards $\tan \theta = 1 / 20$ and therefore $\sin \theta = 1/\sqrt{401}$ : ridiculous value? I've seen worse honestly so I went with it.

but I didn't get the answer exactly right using that so i gave up and checked the solution and there it was given $\sin \theta = 1 / 20$ .

Is this the correct interpretation or mine was correct? Or did they just rounded off $\sqrt{401}$ to $20$ ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Either is reasonable and the question should have used more precise phrasing.  The question writer interpreted $1$ in $20$ as meaning $1$ foot of rise for every $20$ feet along the hill.  You reasonably (and to my mind, a little more naturally) interpreted $1$ in $20$ as meaning $1$ foot of rise for every $20$ feet travelled horizontally.

Comment: It seems like the correct interpretation, if you've watched the Tour de France, you'll notice that they speak in percentages, i.e. a slope of $n %$ means you rise of $n$ meters for $100$ meters.

Comment: $\frac1{20} = 0.05$.  $\frac1{\sqrt{401}}\approx 0.049938$.  The precision suggested difference between them is smaller than the apparent rounding in $98$kg or $6.4$km/h so does this actually make a difference when results will anyway be no better than two significant figures?

Comment: Slope of incline is not ambiguous; the grade of a road has an ambiguous definition many places.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the book is correct here.

Usually, slope (or grade) is determined by the rise in elevation over distance, i.e. $\dfrac {\text {rise}}{\text {run}}$.  In your case, $1 \text { in } 20$ means for each $20$ meters you travel, the elevation increases by $1$ meter.

If you drew a triangle, the rise would be opposite to the hypotenuse, and the run would be adjacent to the hypotenuse.  The Pythagorean Theorem gives the hypotenuse as $\sqrt {1^2 + 20^2} = \sqrt {401}.$  (In decimal notation, $\sqrt {401} = 20.024+$, which is slightly more than $20$.)

However, as we're traveling *along* the hypotenuse, the slope would actually be the rise over the hypotenuse (i.e. $\sin \theta = 1/20$).   (Thanks to TedShifrin for pointing this out!)

Comment: This is the confusion. The distance you travel is the length of the hypotenuse, not the “run.” Yet that is not what is used, despite the sloppy language we find on the web.

Comment: @TedShifrin Agreed...I'm so used to slope being the tangent that I never considered this. 
 I've corrected my post.

Answer (score 0):

"Is this the correct interpretation or mine was correct?"
**Both Interpretations are Exactly Same : Both are Correct.**

"Or did they just rounded off $\sqrt{401}$ to $20$ ?"
**Yes.**

In general , for small angles , $\theta = \sin \theta = \tan \theta$
Here , we have :
$\tan \theta = 0.05000000000$
$\sin \theta = 0.04993761694$
$     \theta = 0.04995839572$

With APPROXIMATIONS , we have :
$\tan \theta = 1/20$
$\sin \theta = 1/20$
$     \theta = 1/20$

Numerically , it will not matter much in the Calculations for Work & Horse Power.

Comment: "Both Interpretations are Exactly Same". No, they are not **exactly** the same. Even for small angles, they are only approximately the same. Also, $\theta \approx \sin \theta$ if $\theta$ is measured in radians, not degrees. So be careful of claiming they are equal where you haven't specified the unit of measure.